# Need to shuffle an array of cards and print them

Tags: c++

I need to a function to shuffle the array of cards I created and a 
  loop 
     in the main that prints the shuffled values. I don't want to change 
        anything 
        else however. The function has to take the 52 cards and the deck size as 
        parameters. Any help with this? My problem is I dont know how to write the shuffle function and print it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Card
{
private:
    string suit;
    string value;

public:

     Card() = default;

    Card(string a, string b)
    {
        value = a;
        suit = b;
    }

    string getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }

    string getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << getValue() << " of " << getSuit() << endl;
    }

    void shuffle(Card cardlist[52], int size)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{



    Card cardlist[52];

    cardlist[0] = Card("2","Spades");
    cardlist[1] = Card("3","Spades");
    cardlist[2] = Card("4","Spades");
    cardlist[3] = Card("5","Spades");
    cardlist[4] = Card("6","Spades");
    cardlist[5] = Card("7","Spades");
    cardlist[6] = Card("8","Spades");
    cardlist[7] = Card("9","Spades");
    cardlist[8] = Card("10","Spades");
    cardlist[9] = Card("Jack","Spades");
    cardlist[10] = Card("Queen","Spades");
    cardlist[11] = Card("King","Spades");
    cardlist[12] = Card("Ace","Spades");
    cardlist[13] = Card("2","Hearts");
    cardlist[14] = Card("3","Hearts");
    cardlist[15] = Card("4","Hearts");
    cardlist[16] = Card("5","Hearts");
    cardlist[17] = Card("6","Hearts");
    cardlist[18] = Card("7","Hearts");
    cardlist[19] = Card("8","Hearts");
    cardlist[20] = Card("9","Hearts");
    cardlist[21] = Card("10","Hearts");
    cardlist[22] = Card("Jack","Hearts");
    cardlist[23] = Card("Queen","Hearts");
    cardlist[24] = Card("King","Hearts");
    cardlist[25] = Card("Ace","Hearts");
    cardlist[26] = Card("2","Diamonds");
    cardlist[27] = Card("3","Diamonds");
    cardlist[28] = Card("4","Diamonds");
    cardlist[29] = Card("5","Diamonds");
    cardlist[30] = Card("6","Diamonds");
    cardlist[31] = Card("7","Diamonds");
    cardlist[32] = Card("8","Diamonds");
    cardlist[33] = Card("9","Diamonds");
    cardlist[34] = Card("10","Diamonds");
    cardlist[35] = Card("Jack","Diamonds");
    cardlist[36] = Card("Queen","Diamonds");
    cardlist[37] = Card("King","Diamonds");
    cardlist[38] = Card("Ace","Diamonds");
    cardlist[39] = Card("2","Clubs");
    cardlist[40] = Card("3","Clubs");
    cardlist[41] = Card("4","Clubs");
    cardlist[42] = Card("5","Clubs");
    cardlist[43] = Card("6","Clubs");
    cardlist[44] = Card("7","Clubs");
    cardlist[45] = Card("8","Clubs");
    cardlist[46] = Card("9","Clubs");
    cardlist[47] = Card("10","Clubs");
    cardlist[48] = Card("Jack","Clubs");
    cardlist[49] = Card("Queen","Clubs");
    cardlist[50] = Card("King","Clubs");
    cardlist[51] = Card("Ace","Clubs");

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        cardlist[i].print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Any help with this?* -- What *specific* problem are you having?

Comment: I simply need to randomize the array of cards and print them using a loop.  (not really simple to me).

Comment: *I simply need to randomize the array of cards*  -- [std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I kinda stole your glory last night. You had the right answer in the comments. In my late night stupor I either didn't see it or my page didn't refresh.

Answer (score 2):

I don't generally help with homework unless it's a one liner. You're in luck though cause it is! (However it's very unlikely that your professor will accept this without an explanation, so you'll need to spend a bit of time understanding *why* this works.)

To rearange the cards we're going to use [`shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle):

```
shuffle(begin(cardlist), end(cardlist), mt19937(random_device()()))
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/MtGSiR)

---

I should also point out here that you have a `shuffle` method in your `Card` class. That makes no sense. Methods are there to operate on an object. Each `Card` is a distinct playing card, who's properties can be operated on by it's methods. You don't shuffle the Ace of Spades. You shuffle a deck of cards. Therefore if you're going to create a `Deck` class that contains 52 `Card` objects it would make sense to make the `Deck::shuffle` method, because you do in fact shuffle a deck of cards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rand()` function to randomly generate two numbers and then just exchange cards having those two numbers as their index.

Adding a For loop allows you randomise the shuffling more.

```
void shuffle(Card cardlist[52], int size)
{
    int v2;
    int v1;
    int loop=rand() % 100;
    for(int i=0;i<loop;i++)
        {   v1 = rand() % size;
            v2 = rand() % size;
            Card temp=cardlist[v1];
            cardlist[v1]=cardlist[v2];
            cardlist[v2]=temp;
    }
```

Note that this is Assuming you need the shuffle function as a member of the class Card

It is better to make it a friend function of the class Card .

Comment: Even if it randomizes the deck, your distribution is not uniform.

Comment: There are a number of problems here:
1) You swap `loop` `Card`s, which could be 1 or even 0
2) You use `rand`; don't do that: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful
3) The number `52` is ignored by the compiler, please don't put it there lest you mislead someone
4) Rather than `temp` you should use `swap`
5) You're poorly reimplementing standard functionality, while that may be what the OP's professor wants it's really very bad in practice

Comment: Being a beginner myself this was a something I tried ...I did not know about the background of rand()